# How to remap Caps Lock to Win key?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an IBM Model M keyboard that doesn't have a `Win` key, and I'd like to remap `CapsLock` using Autohotkey.

Ideally, I'd like to remap all possible combinations at once (eg. `CapsLock`->`Windows`) rather than having to treat each combination in a seaprate line (eg. `CapsLock+Shift+W` -> `Win+Shift+W`)

The script below works for simple key combos, like `Win+R`.

```
*Capslock::Send "{LWin down}"
*Capslock Up::Send "{LWin up}"
```

But it's not working when I press down multiple modifier keys, for example `Win+Shift+W`.

The simple remap below also isn't working for combined modifiers:

```
Capslock::LWin
```

If I open On Screen Keyboard, remove focus, and press down `CapsLock` and `L-Alt`, it shows me both `Win` and `L-Alt` are pressed.

Pressing the thrid key, for example `W`, would not be shown by On Screen Keyboard even when using a real `Win` key on another keyboard.

Comment: How do you define `Win+Shift+W` in your script?

Comment: Using `Capslock::LWin` works fine for me. I'm able to press CapsLock+E and it opens File Explorer, just as Windows+E would.  Shift+CapsLock+S takes a screenshot, etc. What works and doesn't work when you try it?

Comment: I'll add that even though with `Capslock::LWin` all hotkeys (such as Shift+CapsLock+S) work fine for me, OnScreenKeyboard does not accurately show the resulting keys. For example, OSK shows both Capslock and Windows being pressed, even though the state of CapsLock is never toggled. The third key (such as S) is also not shown as pressed on the OSK keyboard, yet the OS still interprets the third key and triggers the shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. `Win+Shift+W` is a built-in ConEmu shortcut key for a new custom tab. I didn't define it specifically in the AH script, as I was hoping to remap all keys in bulk. Meanwhile I've switched to another keyboard that does have a `Win` key :)